# Test Unit Capybara not able to get query last inserted record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, testunit

I am using test unit with fixtures using the standard rails testing framework. I am running some tests using capybara and I am unable to find the last inserted record when I run my model find after the insert. I open up my database editor and I see the record did get inserted properly. I can't figure out wether it's in a transaction and there is a method to get at that data or if it's even possible to get at it. I have even tried using raw SQL from my debugger window and that doesn't work. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: did you find any solution for that problem

Answer (score 0):

The standard rails testing framework runs each test in a database transaction. As soon as the test is complete the data changes are rolled back. This allows each test to start with the same data, and allows the tests to be run in a random order to ensure you don't create any dependencies between tests.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I am wondering is there a way to reach back into the transaction and find the last record that was part of that transaction. I suppose not?

Comment: There might be, but I'm not aware of it. If your database is using an auto-increment primary key (most do) then you can try `Widget.order(:id).last`.